# Flex items don't break on new lines and cause overflow in IOS 9.0

Tags: html, css, flexbox, mobile-safari

It works in other browsers but not in Safari. I need that flex items take the whole width on screens below 768px. They take the whole width of their container but they stay in the same line and I need each item on its own line. `wrap` is the value of `flex-wrap` which display elements in a new lines when there isn't enough space in the main axis, is not working on Safari 9.0 and I would like to know why is that happening. If each element is 100% wide then there isn't enough space for 2 elements and new lines should be created.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 0%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
   .flex-item{
      min-width: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: red">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, perferendis! Excepturi beatae sequi ipsum, temporibus obcaecati reprehenderit dolore expedita nisi facere alias optio maiores recusandae unde! Voluptas minus atque adipisci!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: orange">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, corrupti eaque quos recusandae molestias provident voluptate obcaecati consequuntur quasi perspiciatis nam fugit quibusdam deleniti sit enim adipisci repellendus? Eum, nisi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here below is how my example look like on chrome

[image]

And here is how my example look like on Iphone (Safari 9.0)

[image]

Comment: Safari 9 is like 6 years old at this point. Are you sure Flexbox is fully supported in that version? Also, your provided code does not look like your Chrome image.... are you sure you have provided a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is some sort of bug in safari,
try using

```css
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from an explanation. For example, what are the additional properties here and why would they work where the original ones alone won't?

Comment: We use the additional properties because some browsers do not properly support some CSS properties, in this case, we use '-webkit-flex' to let the browser know that the div is a flexbox.WebKit is the web browser engine used by Safari, Mail, App Store, and many other apps on macOS, iOS, and Linux. (more on WebKit here: https://webkit.org/ ).Hope that helps :)